# How to initialise and create a ResultSet and Record in Jooq?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, jooq

I need to write some unit tests for that I have to mock the Result set and Record with some dummy data. I don't know how to initialize and instantiate them. Please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about your requirements? E.g. what mocking framework are you using, what is your test going to look like, etc.? Also, what have you tried so far? Also, by `ResultSet`, do you mean the JDBC `ResultSet`, or the `org.jooq.Result` ?

Answer (score 3):

jOOQ has a few built-in mock features, see the chapter [JDBC mocking for unit testing](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual-single-page/#jdbc-mocking) of the manual, it might be what you are looking for.

However, to simply create a jOOQ's `Result` or `Record`, you may use the `DSLContext` for that:

```
// Create the record using the jOOQ generated classes and set a property
MyTableRecord record1 = DSL.using(configuration).newRecord(MY_TABLE);
record1.setValue(MY_TABLE.MY_PROPERTY, "value");

// or simply...
MyTableRecord record2 = new MyTableRecord();
record2.setMyProperty("value");

// Then you can populate the Result
Result<MyTableRecord> result = DSL.using(configuration).newResult(MY_TABLE);
result.add(record1);
result.add(record2);
```

You also mention `ResultSet`, if by that you mean the JDBC `ResultSet`, then it might be a bit more complicated to mock that. Instead, I would suggest [DbUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net), that is not a mock for JDBC classes, but you'll assist you to setup your database for tests, which might help you to get the same effects you would have by mocking JBDC classes.