# How to Initialize a custom row type Jooq Record

Tags: java, jooq

Similar to this question: [How to initialise and create a ResultSet and Record in Jooq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452596/how-to-initialise-and-create-a-resultset-and-record-in-jooq) but with a custom row type record rather than a simple table record.
I am instantiating a jooq record to use in mocking, but the record has more than 22 columns and contains rows from many joined tables, so I am using RecordImpl.

```java
RecordImpl r1 = new RecordImpl();
r1.set(COURSE.ID.as("course_id"), 1);
```

This throws exception

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field ("course_id") is not contained in Row ()

Note I am not using RecordImpl directly since it is package private, so I use a

```java
public class RecordWrapper extends RecordImpl {}
```

How can I set fields directly on an untyped Jooq record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't instanciate or extend `RecordImpl` which is part of jOOQ's internal API. Instead, use [`DSLContext.newRecord()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#newRecord-org.jooq.Field...-), e.g.

```java
Record1<Integer> r1 = ctx.newRecord(COURSE.ID.as("course_id")).values(1);
```

Comment: Does it mean that I need to explicitly mention all the fields with their values like `ctx.newRecord(COURSE.ID.as("course_id"), COURSE.ID.as("course_name"),...).values(1, "name",...);`?

Comment: @nabroyan: Yes of course. A record is like a map. It can't just have values. It needs keys (fields) as well.

Comment: I see. What if I have a large query with a lot of joins and `SELECT` contains 30+ columns? Seems `jOOQ` supports up to 22? Is there a way to do mocking for this case?

Comment: @nabroyan: Can you ask a new question please? I'm missing some context.

Comment: I posted a new question with more details :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66185013/unit-test-for-a-large-select-query-with-jooq