# Unit test for a large SELECT query with jOOQ

Tags: java, jooq

I am using `jOOQ` for working with a relational database. I have a `SELECT` query for which I need to write unit tests with mocking. Based on [this](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/mocking-connection/) doc and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45450105/how-to-initialize-a-custom-row-type-jooq-record) post, I need to define my own data provider, which should look something like this:

```
class MyProvider implements MockDataProvider {

    DSLContext create = DSL.using(SQLDialect.MYSQL);

    @Override
    public MockResult[] execute(MockExecuteContext mockExecuteContext) throws SQLException {
        MockResult[] mock = new MockResult[1];
        String sql = mockExecuteContext.sql();

        if (sql.startsWith("select")) {
            Result<Record2<String, String>> result = create.newResult(COL_1, COL_2);
            result.add(create.newRecord(COL_1, COL_2)
                             .values("val1", "val2"));

            mock[0] = new MockResult(1, result);
        }

        return mock;
    }
}
```

where `COL_1` and `COL_2` are defined as follows:

```
Field<String> COL_1 = field("Column1", String.class);
Field<String> COL_2 = field("Column2", String.class);
```

It's quite simple and straightforward when `SELECT` is a small one (as in the above example, just 2 columns). I am wondering how it should be done in case of complex and large selects. For instance I have a `SELECT` statement which selects 30+ columns from multiple table joins. Seems the same approach of

```
Result<Record_X<String, ...>> result = create.newResult(COL_1, ...);
result.add(create.newRecord(COL_1, ...)
                 .values("val1", ...));
```

does not work in case of more than 22 columns.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answering your question

There is no such limitation as a maximum of 22 columns. [As documented here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/record-n/):

> **Higher-degree records**
>
> jOOQ chose to explicitly support degrees up to 22 to match Scala's typesafe tuple, function and product support. Unlike Scala, however, jOOQ also supports higher degrees without the additional typesafety.

You can still construct a record with more than 22 fields using [`DSLContext.newRecord(Field...)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#newRecord(org.jooq.Field...)). Now, there is no `values(Object...)` method on the `Record` type, because the `Record` type is the super type of all the [`Record1`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Record1.html) - [`Record22`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Record22.html) types. If such an overload were present, then the type safety on the sub types would be lost, because the `values(Object...)` method is applicable for all types of arguments. This might be fixed in the future by introducing a [new `RecordN` subtype](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8443).

But you can load data into your record with other means, e.g. by calling [`Record.fromArray(Object...)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Record.html#fromArray(java.lang.Object...)):

```java
Record record = create.newRecord(COL_1, ...);
record.fromArray("val1", ...);
result.add(record);
```

The `values()` method being mere convenience (adding type safety) for `fromArray()`.

#### Disclaimer:

I'm assuming you read the disclaimer on the documentation page you've linked. I'm posting it here anyway for other readers of this question, who might not have read the disclaimer:

> **Disclaimer:** The general idea of mocking a JDBC connection with this jOOQ API is to provide quick workarounds, injection points, etc. using a very simple JDBC abstraction. It is *NOT RECOMMENDED* to emulate an entire database (including complex state transitions, transactions, locking, etc.) using this mock API. Once you have this requirement, please consider using an actual database instead for integration testing, rather than implementing your test database inside of a MockDataProvider.

It seems you're about to re-implement a database which can "run" any type of query, including a query with 23+ columns, and every time you change the query under test, you will also change this test here. I still recommend you do integration testing instead, using [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) or even with H2, which will help cover *many more* queries than any such unit test approach. Here's a quick example showing how to do that: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/main/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-testcontainers-example

Also, integration tests will help test query correctness. Unit tests like these will only provide dummy results, irrespective of the actual query. It is likely that such mocks can be implemented much more easily on a higher level than the SQL level, i.e. by mocking the DAO, or repository, or whatever methods, instead.